# Django how to remove #modal from url

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a modal for confirm the action and this modal adds #modal to url but after i submit the url it stil there in the url even after i did redirect in views.py

```html
<div class="wf-modal" aria-hidden="true" id="{{sepet.id}}">
    <article class="wf-dialog-modal">
      <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="wf-content-modal">
          <input type="hidden" name="cancel-id" value="{{sepet.id}}">
          <label for="sebep">{%if sepet.siparis_durumu.durum == "Kargoya Verildi"%}İade{%else%}İptal{%endif%} Sebebi: </label>
          <textarea name="sebep" style="resize: none; margin-left: 2px;" cols="40" rows="5" {%if sepet.siparis_durumu.durum == "Kargoya Verildi"%}required{%endif%}></textarea>
        </div>
        <footer class="wf-footer-modal">
          <button name="gonder" value="gonder">Gönder</button>
          <a href=""><button name="iptal" type="button">İptal</button></a>
        </footer>
      </form>
    </article>
</div>
```

***views.py***

```
if req.get('gonder'):
   if ...:
     return redirect('/hesabim/iptal/')
```

but the url stil like `/hesabim/iptal/#modal-id`

Comment: The fragment is *never* send to the server, so likely this is a problem with the JavaScript part of your site.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i'v even tried to redirect to other view and then redirect to the view that i want and it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've Solved it by js depending on @WillemVanOnsem comment using:

```
window.location.hash = '';
```